как в параметре слеш команды получать цвет для создания роли?
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что нужно получить цвет для создания роли через команду.
вот код:
@commands.slash_command(name='кастомная_роль', description='создать свою кастомную роль после ее покупки')
    async def castomrole(self, inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction, название: str, цвет: str):
        author = inter.author
        role1 = inter.guild.get_role(1264837983039782923)
        if role1 in author.roles:
            role2 = await inter.guild.create_role(name = f'{название}', colour = disnake.colour(f'{цвет}'))
            await author.add_roles(role2)
            await author.remove_roles(role1)
        else:
            await inter.response.send_message('Упс, кажется ты не покупал возможность создать кастомную роль в нашем магазине\nПопробуй купить ее используя /магазин', ephemeral=True)

Тут, наверно, нужен какой-то конвертер в hex, подскажите плиз.

вопрос решался легко, я просто запутался в аргументах)
